# How to set new value for existing environmental variable

Tags: environment-variables

I have a environmental variable called "PATH" which has a value, now I want to append a new value to the existing value of a variable "PATH" and to set it permanently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To append to `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/extra/directory/here"
```

To make it 'permanent', add that line to `~/.profile`

Comment: adding the line to `~/.profile` will make it permanent for **your user account.**